# Как изменить цвет диапазоне?

Tags: css, vue.js

Нашел в интернете nouislider и как понял за закраску диапазона отвечает .noUi-connect , присваиваю ему background и ничего не закрашивается , в чем проблема ?

```js
 const app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data() {
      return {
         minRange: null,
         maxRange: null,
         slider: {
            startMin: 25,
            startMax: 75,
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            start: 40,
            step: 1
         } 
      }
   },
   methods: {
      updateSlider: function updateSlider() {
        this.$refs.slider.noUiSlider.set([this.minRange, this.maxRange]);
      }
   },
   mounted: function() {
      noUiSlider.create(this.$refs.slider, {
        start: [this.slider.startMin, this.slider.startMax],
        step: this.slider.step,
        range: {
          'min': this.slider.min,
          'max': this.slider.max
        }
      }); 
              
      this.$refs.slider.noUiSlider.on('update',(values, handle) => {
        this[handle ? 'maxRange' : 'minRange'] = parseInt(values[handle]);
      }); 
   }
});
```

```css
.noUi-target, .noUi-target * {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-touch-action: none;
    touch-action: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.noUi-target {
    position: relative;
}
.noUi-base, .noUi-connects {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1
}
.noUi-connects {
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 0
}
.noUi-connect, .noUi-origin {
    will-change: transform;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform-style: flat
}
.noUi-txt-dir-rtl.noUi-horizontal .noUi-origin {
    left: 0;
    right: auto
}
.noUi-vertical .noUi-origin {
    top: -100%;
    width: 0
}
.noUi-horizontal .noUi-origin {
    height: 0
}
.noUi-handle {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute
}
.noUi-touch-area {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%
}
.noUi-state-tap .noUi-connect, .noUi-state-tap .noUi-origin {
    -webkit-transition: transform .3s;
    transition: transform .3s
}
.noUi-state-drag * {
    cursor: inherit!important
}
.noUi-horizontal {
    height: 18px
}
.noUi-horizontal .noUi-handle {
    
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #000000;
    right: -17px;
    top: -6px
}
.noUi-vertical {
    width: 18px
}
.noUi-vertical .noUi-handle {
    width: 28px;
    height: 34px;
    right: -6px;
    bottom: -17px
}
.noUi-txt-dir-rtl.noUi-horizontal .noUi-handle {
    left: -17px;
    right: auto
}
.noUi-target {
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
   border-radius: 6px;
   width: 418px;
   height: 10px;
}
.noUi-connects {
    border-radius: 3px
}
.noUi-connect {
   background: linear-gradient(91.45deg, #0098FF 26.77%, #0066FF 76.25%);
}
.noUi-draggable {
    cursor: ew-resize
}
.noUi-vertical .noUi-draggable {
    cursor: ns-resize
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="./nouislider.min.css">
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/11.0.3/nouislider.min.js"></script>
   <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.7.0/dist/vue.js"></script>
   <div class="" id="app">
      <div id="slider" ref="slider"></div>
      <br>
      <input v-model="minRange" v-on:change="updateSlider" />
            
      <input v-model="maxRange" v-on:change="updateSlider"/>
      </div>
   </div>
   <script src="./qwe.js"></script>
   <script src="./nouislider.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что у вас в сгенерированном браузером коде НЕТ элемента с классом `.noUi-connect`.